# iOS - UIActivityIndicator causing "Hides when stopped but is neither hidden or animating" warning

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nib, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm getting this warning for every nib file that contains a `UIActivityIndicator`. 
The warning states:
 `Unsupported Configuration: Hides when stopped but is neither hidden or animating`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: please post any related code

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This means, You have set `Hides when stopped`.

So there must be two states only,

1. Hidden
2. Animating

But you have set neither Hidden nor Animating.

See the image:

[image]

It must be `Hidden` or `Animating`, If you have Checked `Hides when stopped`.

Comment: The wonderful world of Xcode and its non-sense decisions. This is an option that is a complete waste of time in the universe. Xcode should have 0.01% of intelligence to know that because this hidden property have another meaning on other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

You have selected hide when stopped option but you are never hiding activityindicator. set you setting as in attached image

[image]